# New Blender Animation Doesn't Save

Tags: animation, dopesheet

Anytime I create a new animation there's a 0 next to it and upon exporting it to unity it doesn't show up in the new animations. I've searched this question but I can't find any answers regarding this. Or maybe I'm not asking it right. "Action" and "Shoot" are new animations and no matter what, I can't get them to save. I'm a newbie at using blender so it's completely possible that I'm missing something.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Blender have this system of "orphan data", which are data used nowhere in Blender. These are marked with the `0` you noticed, and get cleared out of the .blend file when closing it.

To prevent that, you need to assign them a "fake user".

There are two main ways to do this:

1. In the data list itself:

[image: data list]

2. In the Outliner Editor > Orphan Data display mode:

[image: outliner]

Comment: Thank you for your response but I fixed this issue by pressing "Push Down" which is to the left of the animation  name in the action editor. Sorry about the confusion

Comment: That isn't really "the" solution. That puts the action data in a different track of your Non-Linear Animation Editor. Which will have unexpected effects if you don't know what you are doing.